# Windows 10 VM with VS Code installed failing to import pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I went ahead and deployed a brand new windows 10 virtual machine. I installed VS code from code.visualstudio.com/downloads and followed the installation instructions. I loaded all of the extensions that was recommended.  Python, DNS Python , MONGODB

I then opened a terminal and ran the pip install pymongo and pip install pymongo[srv] both completed successfully.

I proceeded to create a brand new python file project with only the line "Import pymongo".  The following message is what i get when all is said and done.

import "pymongo" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports).

At this point I have changed my interpreter per the directions I have previously gone through and the end result is the same.

does anyone have any idea on what the next step is? Changing the interpreter doesn't help.